# MySQL delete similar records after insert with Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, innodb

I have MySQL database running with InnoDB engine. I have table which has columns id, nickname, score (so it's a scoreboard).

I need to check AFTER INSERT all rows and find similar record, if there is one delete old one.

`USE 'database';`

`DELIMITER $$`

`CREATE TRIGGER tests_AINS AFTER INSERT ON tests FOR EACH ROW`
`-- Edit trigger body code below this line. Do not edit lines above this one`

So how do I proceed?

Comment: See if `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` is a better way to do the task (without triggers).

Comment: Yes, that would be logical way to do it, I'm just in a need to learn use triggers and find good usages for them.

Comment: Check for trigger examples in the new documentation area:  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=mysql&query=trigger